# Manipulating a text string (for the purpose of converting a date format to custom date format)

Tags: jquery

I have dates being output in this format: 14-MAR-2011 (DD-MMM-YYYY) for example.

Is it possible, using jQuery to convert this to: 03\11 (MM\YY) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can try:

```
var value = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy",date);
return $.datepicker.formatDate("dd\mm",value);
```

See [datepicker API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)

You just need jquery.ui (maybe you use it...)

> but how would I now make your code
>   work to format all dates say in a div
>   classed "date"? eg: 14-MAR-2011

Somerthing like that in your jquery script (not tested, but should works after corrected possible bugs ;):

```
$('.date').each(function(idx,elt) {
  var value = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy",$(elt).html());
  $(elt).html($.datepicker.formatDate("dd\mm",value));
});
```

Comment: Thanks this looks promising... but where do I actually put this?
I've now added the jQuery UI (with DatePicker) to my site, but how would I now make your code work to format all dates say in a div classed "date"? eg: <div class"date">14-MAR-2011</div>

Comment: Awesome!
Just had to change the formatDate to: "mm\\y"
to get into desired format and to include to backslash
THANK YOU Benoit

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/):

```
var date = Date.parseExact('14-MAR-2011', 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
alert(date.toString('dd\\MM'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well JQuery provides a bunch of useful tools, but I think for this things you should just use classic javascript.
If Date.parse() and date.toDateString() isn't what you need, you may take a look at [here](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to work a lot with dates, I would recommend the very robust Datejs lib: http://www.datejs.com/

If you are just going to parse that specific format (as in no subject to variate), you can use substringing techniques and a bit of logic such as this:

```
var badFormat = '14-DEC-2011', // input
    goodFormat = badFormat.substr(9), // YY
    month = badFormat.substr(3, 3); // MMM

// a switch statement would be long and readable (probably recommended)
if(month[0] == 'J')
    if(month[1] == 'U')
        month = month[2] == 'N' ? 6 : 7;
    else month = 1;
else if(month[0] == 'F') month = 2;
else if(month[0] == 'M')
    month = month[2] == 'R' ? 3 : 5;
else if(month[0] == 'A')
    month = month[1] == 'P' ? 4 : 8;
else if(month[0] == 'S') month = 9;
else if(month[0] == 'O') month = 10;
else if(month[0] == 'N') month = 11;
else month = 12;

month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
goodFormat = month + '\\' + goodFormat; // MM\YY
```